# redux-observable epic typescript warning: 'store' is declared but its value is never read

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-observable

I have a `redux observable epic` as below

```
export const fetchUserEpic:Epic<Action, RootState, any> = 
    (action$: ActionsObservable<Action>, store: MiddlewareAPI<RootState> , { getJSON } ): Observable<Action> => 
        action$.filter((action: Action) => action.type === actionTypes.FETCH_USER)
            .mergeMap(  (action: Action) =>
                getJSON(`/api/user/${action.payload}`)
                .map((response: any) => Actions.fetchUserSuccess(response))
            )
```

Everything works fine and the *tests* are great, but on compiling the **typescript** code, I get the following warning

```
semantic error TS6133 'store' is declared but its value is never read.
```

How do I resolve this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a linting error from TypeScript noUnusedParameters aka no-unused-variable setting. It means that your function has the `store` parameter defined but does not actually use it. To fix you can prefix the store parameter with an underscore `_store` and it will ignore it, or you can remove the linting option from either your tsconfig or your compiler flags.

```
(action$: ActionsObservable<Action>, _store: MiddlewareAPI<RootState> , { getJSON } ): Observable<Action>
```

This works because the TypeScript compiler explicitly added this convention as an exception to the linting rule. It was done for exactly these sorts of cases.

Comment: Excellent. your answer works like a charm and also it's not dirty. And also if I need to use the *store* I can refer the `_store` variable. But can you explain why `_store` works? @jayphelps

Comment: Great to hear! This works because the TypeScript compiler explicitly added this convention as an exception to the linting rule. It was done for exactly these sorts of cases.

Answer (score 0):

I know its kind of dirty, but I somehow found the solution to this issue and it resolves the warning.

From the code:

```
export const fetchUserEpic:Epic<Action, RootState, any> = 
    (action$: ActionsObservable<Action>, store: MiddlewareAPI<RootState> , { getJSON } ): Observable<Action> => 
        action$.filter((action: Action) => action.type === actionTypes.FETCH_USER)
            .mergeMap(  (action: Action) =>
                getJSON(`/api/user/${action.payload}`)
                .map((response: any) => Actions.fetchUserSuccess(response))
            )
```

I know that `store` variable is not being used anywhere inside the `function`. But since the *function signature* demands it, So I simply declare an *empty object* `{}` instead of the `store` variable.

The resulting code will be:

```
export const fetchUserEpic:Epic<Action, RootState, any> = 
    (action$: ActionsObservable<Action>, {}: MiddlewareAPI<RootState> , { getJSON } ): Observable<Action> => 
        action$.filter((action: Action) => action.type === actionTypes.FETCH_USER)
            .mergeMap(  (action: Action) =>
                getJSON(`/api/user/${action.payload}`)
                .map((response: any) => Actions.fetchUserSuccess(response))
            )
```

and the warning gets resolved. If I need to use the **store** inside the epic, I can simply define the `store` variable in the function parameters.